# Amazon EC2 Windows with Sql Server Web, changed to an instance with just Windows no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

If I start a windows AMI with Sql Server Web, this will include a licensed Sql Server Web installation.

What will happen if I then create a Windows only AMI instance and connect the volume with Sql Server Web to it.

I'm not actually planning on doing this, but would that work? So I'm effectively no longer paying the extra cost per hour that includes the Sql Server Web license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon keeps track of the lineage of the AMI and knows what initial image was used to create your resulting AMI. You'll be charged based on the rates commensurate with the parent AMI. Why don't you just the the BASE Windows 2008 or 2012 AMI ?